# How do i store my registration details in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a registration webpage for my project but i want to store the details in local storage but it doesn't seem to save the phone number and address details. I've checked the developer tools in Google Chrome (only browser i prefer to use) and it shows only the username, password, and email address being saved into local storage... any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are accidentally using "Password" three times. It should also be affecting address.

```
localStorage.PassWord = passW;
var address = document.getElementById("Address1").value;
localStorage.PassWord = address;
var phoneN = document.getElementById("PhoneNumber").value;
localStorage.PassWord = phoneN;
```

Change it to:

```
localStorage.PassWord = passW;
var address = document.getElementById("Address1").value;
localStorage.Address = address;
var phoneN = document.getElementById("PhoneNumber").value;
localStorage.PhoneNumber = phoneN;
```

Comment: Haha, i am absolutely knackered. But this is the learning curve i guess, spot small things to make big things. Thanks alot anyways! @mseifert